# html mailto: equivalent for sending an appointment request

Tags: html

I have a link  which when clicked opens up your default email program.  Is there a command that opens up a meeting request (i.e. with outlook) dialog?

could not post a screen shot because i don't have enough "reputation points" so hopefully my question is clear on its own.

Comment: I am 99% sure that there is no such thing. email is an essential part of the web, so browsers support such intengration since ages ago, but other outlook functions dont integrate with your browser in such a manner.

Comment: this is the link href="mailto:?subject=Reminder (stackoverflow stripped it out of my original post)

Answer (score 3):

If possible, try linking directly to an .ics or .vcs file.

Answer (score 1):

`mailto` is a protocol, but there isn't an official protocol for calendars.

You could try the `webcal` protocol (i.e. webcal:calendar.example.com), but I don't know what browser support is like. Alternatively, link to a .ics or .vcs file.

Answer (score 0):

### Using Outlook Command-Line

While there is no protocol for a new calendar appointment, it's possible to run Outlook.exe from the command-line and have it start a new appointment with the following [command-line switch](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/command-line-switches-for-microsoft-office-products-079164cd-4ef5-4178-b235-441737deb3a6#Category=Outlook):

```
outlook /c ipm.appointment
```

[image: Outlook new appointment command-line]

This opens a new appointment window:

[image: New Outlook meeting window]